# How do I extent multiple components' styles in styled-components

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I have these Components:...

```
const Card = () => <span>There is content</span>

const CardItem = styled(Card)`
  background-color: red;
`
```

Now I want another component from the above like this:

```
const Card2 = styled(CardItem)`
  background-color: green;
`
```

For my third I item, I want all the above styles extended as well as extend `button` html element.

This is how I did it...

```
Card3 = Card2.withComponent('button').extend`
  pointer-events: none;
`
```

But this, I get Card 2 rendered as `<span>There is content</span>` but Card 3 is just an empty `There is NO content

I understand `withComponent` only replaces the tags(idk), but how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

A few things to get this working:

**First**, Styled Components transforms your CSS into CSS classes and then attaches those classes to React components via the `className` prop.  That means in order for the style to actually get applied, you have to make sure that the `className` prop is being handled.  Right now the Card component isn't doing that.

You want `<Card>` to accept a `className` prop:

```js
const Card = ({className}) => <span className={className}>There is content</span>
```

That will allow `CardItem` and `Card2` to display as intended.

**Second**, for `Card3`, `withComponent` does not replace the tag, it replaces the whole component.  For this reason, the entirety of `Card` will get swapped out with a button, including the text inside of `Card`.  If you still want that text, here's two possible solutions:

You could pass children into `Card3`:

```js
return <Card3>There is content</Card3>
```

Or you could add a prop for the tag name to the original `Card`:

```js
const Card = (props) => {
  const Tag = props.tag || 'span'
  return <Tag className={props.className}>There is content</Tag>
}

const ButtonCard = props => <Card {...props} tag="button" />

const Card3 = Card2.withComponent(ButtonCard).extend`
  pointer-events: none;
`
```

Comment: It's worth noting that the edge cases in `withComponent` can be totally avoided if you're using the new ["as" prop](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/api#as-polymorphic-prop) in styled-components v4 (currently in beta.)